# Using a Child ApplicationContext to add/override Beans in Parent

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a fairly heavy Spring ApplicationContext (takes long to start/stop) and I wonder whether I can use a child context to add/override beans in the parent. The motivation is to have beans directly available in the parent   (or even overriding parent defs if the need arises) which are driven by a separate lifecyle (start/stop for fast feedback during development).

Can this be done with a child ApplicationContext?

Anything special (like lookup delegation or so) one should be aware of?

Also, I wouln't mind being pointed to other trickery appropriate for the job. ;)

Comment: The short answer is no you cannot do that as the beans in the parent are already fully configured, proxied and what not. It might also be potentially dangerous as what would happen if you change a Bean X which is already in use by 10 other beans? (Currently the old instance is still used). If you have a Bean X in the parent and another one in the child beans from the child will use the Bean x instance from the child and not the parent. If you override or add beans to a context you basically need to refresh (i.e. reload) the context .

Comment: I  am fully aware that doing this might cause a bunch of issues. Just  like code  reloading/swapping does in general when state comes in.

Comment: If it is about development I would suggest taking a look at Spring Loaded or JRebel instead of introducting ugly hacks which at some point will lead to issues in production (is my experience).

Comment: I  was just about to mention JRebel which I think is aware of Spring Bean lifecycle and applies some tricks here.  Spring-Loaded has no clue. Anyways, both introduce an agent and mess with classes. I do not need this and on top of that it even ntroducing further issues.